# Automatic Weights Deforms The Whole Thing

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

[image]

I have a body mesh, added a simple bone setup accordingly and used automatic weights, but it always deforms the whole thing in a weird way. I left all the settings default in 2.8, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Update - this somehow works fine again after remeshing

Answer (score 0):

do not edit bones in pose mode. only edit them in edit mode. pose mode is only for posing the rig!

go to pose mode and ctrl + a to select all. then press alt + g and alt + r and alt + s to set it to default position. edit in edit mode. then do automatic weights.